# Program freezing when calling component.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()

Tags: c#, wpf, dispatcher, ui-thread

**What I want to do:**
I'm using a web service DLL in WPF(c#). The DLL contains a web service that you can see it in my code as `SmsSender` class. Calling each method of this class is *time-consuming* so I need run its methods in other threads.

**What I do:** 
I set DataView object (that is "returned value" from method) to ItemsSource of DataGrid. So I use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`.

**My problem:**
 my problem is using `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` can freeze my program even I run it in a different thread. I want to call method without freezing. Is it possible to define a time-out?

**Update1:**

How can I set DataView from time-consuming method to DataGrid?

My code:

```
Action action = () =>
{
    SmsSender sms = new SmsSender();

    dgUser1.ItemsSource = sms.GetAllInboxMessagesDataSet().Tables[0].DefaultView;
};

dgUser1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is by design. `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` should only be called on to do work that interacts with the UI.

Comment: how can I redesign my project? Any Idea?

Comment: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` executes a delegate on the thread the `Dispatcher` was created on. Usually you use it to be able to update something on the UI thread **from another thread**. Since you include the time-consuming call in the delegate this means that everything is running on the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats easy. You should NEVER do blocking I/O on your UI thread.

```
SmsSender sms = new SmsSender();
DataView result = sms.GetAllInboxMessagesDataSet().Tables[0].DefaultView
Action action = () =>
{
    dgUser1.ItemsSource = result;
};
dgUser1.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
```

However this is actually NOT how you should write WPF apps. This pattern is done using WinForms like patterns. You should REALLY be using DataBinding.

Databinding would take care of all your `Dispatcher` calls.

Comment: Thank you Aron. But my UI hanged.

Comment: I'm new in WPF. Would you tell me how use Databinding?

Comment: Beyond the scope of a quick answer here. Please google for WPF tutorials. Anyone will describe the MVVM pattern and how to implement it in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` runs delegate on UI thread and since you have put complete action on dispatcher, it will be executed on UI thread which results in UI hang issue.

There are many ways to delegate time consuming operation on to background thread and dispatch UI calls on UI thread.

Simple example is to use `BackgroundWorker`. Put non-UI stuff in `DoWork` event handler and UI operation on `RunWorkerCompleted` handler which is called on UI thread only so need to dispatch calls to UI disptacher.

Small sample -

```
BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
worker.RunWorkerCompleted +=
        new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_RunWorkerCompleted);
worker.RunWorkerAsync();

void worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   dgUser1.ItemsSource = (DataView)e.Result;
}        

void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   SmsSender sms = new SmsSender();
   e.Result = sms.GetAllInboxMessagesDataSet().Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You should use Dispatcher in worker_DoWork body. +1 for you

Comment: _DoWork needs Dispatcher only in case `SmsSender` is UI object. If not than no need to use dispatcher.